# Combining two MySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query1 = 'select DATE_FORMAT(time, "%Y-%m-%d") as date,
        count(*) as phone_TotalPerDay
        from numrequest
        where id_usr = "'.$id_user.'"
        AND id_re ="'.$id_re.'"
        AND request="ph"
        group by id_usr, year(time), DAYOFYEAR(time)
        order by year(time) DESC, DAYOFYEAR(time) DESC';  


$query2 = 'select DATE_FORMAT(time, "%Y-%m-%d") as date,
        count(*) as fax_TotalPerDay
        from numrequest
        where id_usr = "'.$id_user.'"
        AND id_re ="'.$id_re.'"
        AND request="fx"
        group by id_usr, year(time), DAYOFYEAR(time)
        order by year(time) DESC, DAYOFYEAR(time) DESC';
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries. I really need them in one resource.
currently each one is showing number of *number request* per day. I want to combine them so that each `date` has `phone_TotalPerDay` and `fax_TotalPerDay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a conditional sum, something like

```
$query1 = 'select DATE_FORMAT(time, "%Y-%m-%d") as date,
    sum(if(request = "ph", 1, 0)) phone_TotalPerDay,
    sum(if(request = "fx", 1, 0)) fax_TotalPerDay
    from numrequest
    where id_usr = "'.$id_user.'"
    AND id_re ="'.$id_re.'"
    group by id_usr, year(time), DAYOFYEAR(time)
    order by year(time) DESC, DAYOFYEAR(time) DESC';
```

The `if` statements return 1 if the request type matches and 0 otherwise, so summing these effectively counts the rows matching this condition, and I've removed the request criteria from the where clause.